# Installing a LG dvd drive in my antec p183 case

Tags: installation, dvd, optical-drive

I added those silly braces around the drive.

Now I can't slide the drive in from the front now, and even putting it in through the case doesn't seem to work.

how do you do this? haha

Answer (score 1):

The last antec case I used had a quick disconnect cage for the hard drives.  The locking lug was on one side and had a colored lever to unlock it.  If you do not have a case with this feature, you might look to see if the case came with any drive installation rails.  Many manufacturers include case specific hardware.  In my experience these always came either in a bag with the case or these rails were attached somewhere on the inside of the case itself.

Comment: The hard drive cages swing out, but not sure if the top cage for the cd drive etc. comes out? (antec p183)
Yes I installed the rails, but I can't fit the drive into the case now (either from the front or the back!)  When trying to insert the drive through the case, it doesn't seem to lineup because of the rails coming in the way.

Comment: Many cases also force you to remove the front valence to have the full clearance needed to install drives.  In most cases this piece just snaps out of place once the case has been opened.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the front of the case. This can be done by removing both side panels and unclipping the tabs on both sides that hold the front on. After, you can slide the drive into place on the rails and then re-attach the front plate.

Comment: If it's anything like my P180, that's not necessary. I can simply remove a drive by depressing the clip on the rail and sliding it out.

Answer (score 1):

Most optical drives I've seen have two sets of screw holes, did you try both? One set is higher than the other and would cause misalignment when trying to slide the drive in the case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the springy metal parts of the drive rails go at the front of the drive.  (In my experience they almost fit into the cage when they're on backwards, making it hard to guess what you've done wrong.)